# CakePHP 3 Nested Resources Not Working Properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Apologies for the rather vague title, but I'm not sure how else to describe the problem I'm having.

I have an 'admin' prefix route configured, and within that prefix I want to set up nested resources. I have the following set up:

```
Groups hasMany Users
Users hasMany Items
Items hasMany Comments
```

I want my URLs to reflect the relationship between groups, users, items, comments, etc. So for instance, here are some example URLs:

```
/admin/groups (list all groups)
/admin/groups/1 (view group with id 1)
/admin/groups/1/users (list all users for group with id 1)
/admin/groups/1/users/12 (view user with id 12 from group with id 1)
/admin/groups/1/users/12/items (list all items belonging to user with id 12)
...you get the idea.
```

Here is the relevant part of my routes.php file:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {

        $routes->resources('Groups', function ($routes) {
            $routes->resources('Users', function ($routes) {
                $routes->resources('Items', function ($routes) {
                    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
                });
                $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
            });
            $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
        });
        $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
    });

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-nested-resources), this should automatically create routes like the ones I want, and to some degree it does. For instance, going to /admin/groups/ will call the index() function of GroupsController.php, and /admin/groups/1 will call the view($id) function. Even /admin/groups/1/users will work (it calls the index() function of UsersController.php). However, that's as far as it goes.

If I go to /admin/groups/1/users/1, I get the following error message:

```
 The action 1 is not defined in UsersController

 Error: Create UsersController::1() in file: src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php.
```

It seems that the nesting works to some degree, but not as far as I'd expect, and not as far as the documentation says it will.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure that you are using the latest release, and check whether there are any conflicting routes (you can get all connected routes via `Router::routes()`).